# scala - how to substring column names after the last dot?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

After exploding a nested structure I have a DataFrame with column names like this:

```
sales_data.metric1
sales_data.type.metric2
sales_data.type3.metric3
```

When performing a select I'm getting the error:

```
cannot resolve 'sales_data.metric1' given input columns: [sales_data.metric1, sales_data.type.metric2, sales_data.type3.metric3]
```

How should I select from the DataFrame so the column names are parsed correctly?

I've tried the following: the substrings after dots are extracted successfully. But since I also have columns without dots like `date` - their names are getting removed completely.

```
var salesDf_new = salesDf 
for(col <- salesDf .columns){
  salesDf_new = salesDf_new.withColumnRenamed(col, StringUtils.substringAfterLast(col, "."))
}
```

I want to leave just metric1, metric2, metric3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use backticks to select columns whose names include periods.

```
val df = (1 to 1000).toDF("column.a.b")

df.printSchema
// root
//  |-- column.a.b: integer (nullable = false)

df.select("`column.a.b`")
```

Also, you can rename them easily like this.  Basically starting with your current DataFrame, keep updating it with a new column name for each field and return the final result.

```
val df2 = df.columns.foldLeft(df)(
    (myDF, col) => myDF.withColumnRenamed(col, col.replace(".", "_"))
)
```

**EDIT: Get the last component**

To rename with just the last name component, this regex will work:

```
val df2 = df.columns.foldLeft(df)(
    (myDF, col) => myDF.withColumnRenamed(col, col.replaceAll(".+\\.([^.]+)$", "$1"))
)
```

**EDIT 2: Get the last two components**

This is a little more complicated, and there might be a cleaner way to write this, but here is a way that works:

```
val pattern = (
    ".*?"  +          // Lazy match leading chars so we ignore that bits we don't want
    "([^.]+\\.)?" +   // Optional 2nd to last group
    "([^.]+)$"        // Last group
)

val df2 = df.columns.foldLeft(df)(
    (myDF, col) => myDF.withColumnRenamed(col, col.replaceAll(pattern, "$1$2"))
)
df2.printSchema
```

Comment: When I'm using `col.replace(".", "_")` the column names look like this: `sales_data_type_metric2`. What I want is to leave just a substring after the last dot: `metric1`, `metric2`, `metric3`. Keeping in mind that I still have columns without dots and don't need to affect them.

Comment: Added a regex that should accomplish that.

Comment: one more question: how should the regex look like if I want to leave one word before the last dot if it exists like `type.metric2` ?

Comment: Updated again to capture 2nd to last group if present