# How to avoid column names like 'sum(<column>)' in aggregation in Spark/Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

The aggregation

```
df.groupBy($"whatever").sum("A","B","C")
```

produces a DataFrame with column names like `sum(A)`, `sum(B)` and `sum(C)`. Often the names A, B and C are already correct names for the final aggregates. Is there a way to avoid doing this:

```
df.groupBy($"whatever").sum($"A".as("A"), $"B".as("B"), $"C".as("C"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is not.

You need to use alias via .as as you state yourself.

You can of course rename the columns latterly. [scala - how to substring column names after the last dot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51616666/scala-how-to-substring-column-names-after-the-last-dot) provides good guidance here with replaceAll on col name.

Comment: That `replaceAll` is a useful trick. I was also considering writing a vararg function that would map `arg:String -> col(arg).as(arg)`, which you could call something like this: `df.groupBy(...).sum(fixNames("A","B","C"))`